# Can a permanent resident of the US travel to & from Mexico with a Mexican passport?

Tags: usa, international-travel, mexico, us-permanent-residents

My dad’s a permanent resident of the US but he wants to travel to Mexico this year.  Can he use a Mexican passport to go to Mexico and use it to come back?  He has a US ID, US Driver’s license, a Mexican birth certificate, and a social security card.(he is taking a bus to Mexico)

Comment: Is the US ID a green card?  If not, does he have one?  If not, is there anything preventing him from getting one before his trip?

Comment: Traveling by bus does not change that he needs proof of being allowed back into the USA, does he have a Green Card?

Answer (score 3):

> my dad’s a perm resident of the us but he wants to travel to Mexico this year can he use a Mexican passport to go to Mexico

Yes.

> and use it to come back

To come back (whether by air or otherwise), he does not need a passport, but he does need an acceptable document to prove his permanent resident status.  This is normally the green card.  If he doesn't have a green card, he should apply for a new one as soon as possible.

Comment: _"he does not need a passport"_ - so the airline would accept a green card without a passport?  (genuine question)

Comment: This is ONLY correct if entering the US by land.  If entering via air he will absolutely need a passport (Mexico passport is fine).  As the question asked hasn't mention a means of transport, this answer is at best misleading!

Comment: @Midavalo if they follow TIMATIC, yes.

Comment: @Doc actually I believe green card is enough to travel by air, at least from US perspective (they may need a valid passport to exit the country though).

Comment: @Doc not according to https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/US-USA-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm -- do you have a source saying otherwise?

Comment: @Doc: "If entering via air he will absolutely need a passport" Not as far as the US government is concerned. [CBP's carrier information guide](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2023-Nov/Carrier%20Information%20Guide%20ENGLISH.pdf), page 32, says "A Lawful Permanent Resident may travel to the United States without a passport with a Permanent Resident Card (Form I-551)." Of course, just because the US government allow airlines to do it, doesn't mean the airline has to allow it.

Comment: @user102008 Wrongful denial of boarding can lead to a sizeable compensation depending on the region. If the US Gov states you don't need a passport, then the airline can't and will probably not deny you boarding.

Comment: Won't the migration authorities (Mexico in this case) require a valid travel document for the exit check?

Comment: @Ozzy But he could use the same Mexican passport he uses to enter Mexico to exit Mexico.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella: "If the US Gov states you don't need a passport, then the airline can't" Why can't the airline have its own requirements for riding on its planes, beyond what a government requires for entry? i.e. the airline is enforcing its own requirements, not the government's? For example, minors do not need [ID](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification) to to pass airport security checkpoints for a domestic flight, but it says to ask airlines if they have specific ID requirements.

Comment: @user102008 The answer for the compensation lies in what is meant by [*you do not have the correct travel documents*](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#deniedBoarding) (same wording in UK and Turkey). Adding artificial requirements will not make the travel docs change, so you'll have a very good case against the airline if you get denied boarding because of those art. requirements.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella: The US government also says that airlines are allowed to board green card holders with expired 10-year green cards for travel to the US. Are you also suggesting that airlines cannot deny boarding to such a person? But [I-131A page](https://www.uscis.gov/i-131a), Special Instructions, clearly contemplates that airlines might do this ("In some situations, they may refuse to let you board even if you are in one of the categories above.")

Comment: @A.R. ah well yes, sorry, I thought the discussion was about whether or not a passport was needed at all.